# Is there an option to remove duplicate point labels within a distance in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox Studio to label some point features (from a GeoJSON layer I uploaded) in a style, and there are some duplicate points located nearby each other:

[image]

Are there any options in Mapbox Studio to remove the duplicate labels automatically? For example, some other mapping programs have the option to remove duplicate labels within a specified distance (pixels or map units). Is this available in Mapbox Studio (or failing that, in Mapbox-GL-JS)?

Comment: Is this from your own data you've added and is the duplicated in the source data?

The only option I see is to clean this in the source data, or if the features have a unique ID, manually filter out the duplicates based on ID.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey yep they are genuine duplicates, and are spatially unique. (They're _station exits_, but I only want to label each _station_ once). I was hoping Mapbox would have an option like Maplex which can ignore nearby duplicates, but fair enough if I have to pre-process them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox Studio does not provide a way to remove the duplicate labels automatically. You could work with a [filter](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/) to manually filter out duplicates by writing a relatively complex [expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/), although this is not really the intended use case of expressions. You could also add a `duplicate: true` property to duplicated point features in your source data, but since this would require manipulating your source data, you might as well remove the duplicates from the source data instead of taking this approach.

That being said, you could consider clustering your data and styling the clusters so that a cluster looks the same as any individual point. [This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/) shows how to create and style clusters using Mapbox GL JS. Here is a JSFiddle that heavily modifies this example to cluster closely-located points, and style the clusters in the same way that individual points are styled: https://jsfiddle.net/uo216fxz/ (you will need to add your own Mapbox access token in order to view the result). Text labels are added with the point count for each cluster containing more than one point, so that you can easily see that clusters and single points are identical aside from the labeling.

You will likely need to customize several properties (such as `clusterRadius`, `clusterMaxZoom`, etc) beyond what is provided in the linked JSFiddle, to be more specific to your source data.